# ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (1, 4) in python

Tags: python

i am getting ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (1, 4),while running below code:

when below code run for source then it gives output like-

```
srcoutput                                              Records
0     bill_no  bill_date cust_code  amount
0     ...
```

when code ran for target then it gives output like-

```
tgt output    bill_no                 bill_date cust_code  amount
0        7 2013-06-11 00:00:00+00:00      C234   542.0
1        8 2013-07-24 00:00:00+00:00      C003   300.0
2        2 2013-01-25 00:00:00+00:00      C003   456.5
3        5 2013-04-19 00:00:00+00:00      C234   656.0
```

"CODE"

```
def dupes_record(df_processed,db_type):
    try:
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + df_processed["schema_table"] + ' WHERE ' + df_processed[
                "column_name"] + ' IN (SELECT ' + df_processed["column_name"] + '\
                   FROM ' + df_processed["schema_table"] + ' group by ' + df_processed[
                      "column_name"] + ' having count(*)>1)'
        print("sql",sql)

        if db_type == 'BIGQUERY':
            sql = sql[0]
            print("src",sql)
            df6_read = db_conn.query(sql)
            df6= df6_read.result().to_dataframe()
            print("tgt output", df6)
            return df6
        df6 = pd.DataFrame()
        df6["Records"] = sql[sql.notna()].apply(
            lambda i: pd.read_sql_query(i, db_connection))
        df6.reset_index(drop=True)
        print("srcoutput",df6)
        return df6
```

have tried to add Records column in target but its not added and it give null output.
have tried below:

```
"1"
df6_read = db_conn.query(sql)
            df6 = pd.DataFrame()
            df6["Records"] = df6_read.result().to_dataframe()
ERROR:Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (4, 4) 
"2"

df6_read = db_conn.query(sql)
            df6 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Records"])
            df6= df6_read.result().to_dataframe()

ERROR:ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (1, 4)
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please add the error traceback in the question as well?

Comment: @medium-dimensional ,errors has been added in question.

Comment: It looks like `df6_read.result().to_dataframe()` returns a data frame with shape 4 x 4, but it should be an array since it is assigned to the column `Records`. You can try reshaping it to 1 x 16, but it depends on what actual data is. Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which would help in solving the issue.